# Adding Dynamic members to a class

Tags: c#, xml

**My Class:**

```
public partial class Data
{
    Public string Name { get;set }
    Public int Age { get; set }
}
```

**XML Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Age>49</Age>    
</Data>
```

I am generating the above xml based on the Data class .Is there a way I can add a new member on the fly to my class say "Gender" with out re compiling the class so that it would reflect in the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add members to your object at runtime, you can use an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Alternatively, you could add a `List` to store additional runtime information, or modify the XML after you've serialized the object (if you only need the data in the XML and not in the object itself).

Comment: `ExpandoObject`s and `dynamic` in general have become my new friends.

Comment: ExpandoObject is part of .NET 4.0 i guess and If I have to go for earlier version of .NET would dynamic be my answer ?

Comment: @Macnique `dynamic` is .NET 4. If you're using an earlier version, you can do something very similar by adding a `Dictionary<string, object>` to your class. You can then Add/Remove/Update "properties" via the dictionary. An ExpandoObject is basically exactly that, but with a little compiler magic to make it more user friendly.